# "Could not create the JVM" error at Eclipse startup

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got error like this:

[image: JVM Launcher]

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M
-showsplash com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

--launcher.defaultAction openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can start eclipse this way instead:

```
eclipse -vm <path to java>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `eclipse.ini file` change the following

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
900m
```

from

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
```

Also check out this [link](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/java-problem.68817/) and mostly this error comes due to the hardware issues like the RAM.

Comment: Like this?-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
900m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: @АкмальСалихов:- Yes you can give it a try! Also there are other places also where you need to change the value above

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened with me when i updated my jre7 , what worked for me was updating the new path in windows environment variables, 
add a new system variable :

Variable Name: PATH

Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin

hope this helps..:)